# LiveCharts ColumnSeries not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm using LiveCharts in WPF to visualize the results of some analyses. The results of an analysis is added to a SeriesCollection and displayed in an CartesianChart. You can choose which type of series to use: LineSeries or ColumnSeries. The chosen type is then created and added to the SeriesCollection.

There's a custom mapper for selecting X and Y values from the ChartValues and a AxisFormatter for the X axis.

The charts are part of an Blacklight.Controls.Wpf.DragDockPanelHost. Each chart is an DragDockPanel with a style attached to it. The chart itself is a ContentControl with an TemplateSelector that returns the CartesianChart-XAML as a DataTemplate.

I've already tried to set the Fill or Stroke of the series or putting some ColumnSeries in there manually but that didn't help at all.

Filling of the SeriesCollection:

```
private SeriesCollection _Series;
public SeriesCollection Series
{
    get { return _Series; }
    set { SetProperty<SeriesCollection>(ref _Series, value); }
}

...

private void createDiagram()
{
    if (this._Analysis!= null && this._Diagram != null)
    {
        this.Series.Clear();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<state, Dictionary<DateTime, int>> kvp in this.Analysis.Execute())
        {
            Series series = Activator.CreateInstance(Diagram) as Series;
            if (series != null)
            {
                series.Title = kvp.Key.name;
                series.Values = new ChartValues<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>(kvp.Value);
                this.Serien.Add(series);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mapper and AxisFormatter:

```
CartesianMapper<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> mapper = Mappers.Xy<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>().X(kvp => ((DateTimeOffset)kvp.Key).ToUnixTimeSeconds()).Y(kvp => kvp.Value);
this.Series = new SeriesCollection(mapper);
this.XFormatter = value =>
{
    return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds((long)value).DateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
};
```

TemplateSelector:

```
public class DashboardElementTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
  {
    public DataTemplate ListDashboardElementTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SingleValueDashboardElementTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
      if (item is ListDashboardElementViewModel)
        return this.ListDashboardElementTemplate;
      else
        return this.SingleValueDashboardElementTemplate;
    }
  }
```

XAML of DragDockPanelHost:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="listElement">
            <views:ListDashboardElementView/>
          </DataTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="singleValueElement">
            <views:SingleValueDashboardElementView/>
          </DataTemplate>
          <tempselect:DashboardElementTemplateSelector x:Key="elementTempSelector"
                                                       ListDashboardElementTemplate="{StaticResource listElement}"
                                                       SingleValueDashboardElementTemplate="{StaticResource singleValueElement}"
                                                       />
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <conv:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visCon"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>

<bl:DragDockPanelHost ItemsSource="{Binding Diagrams}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <bl:DragDockPanelHost.Style>
        <Style TargetType="bl:DragDockPanelHost">
          <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                </Canvas>
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="bl:DragDockPanelHost">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </bl:DragDockPanelHost.Style>
      <bl:DragDockPanelHost.DefaultPanelStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type bl:DragDockPanel}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10">
                  <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                      <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="#00000000" Margin="-2" Padding="5" Grid.Row="0">
                      <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <WrapPanel>
                          <Image Width="20" x:Name="GripBarElement" Source="/Aisys.XStorage.Dashboard;component/Images/move.png" Grid.Column="0" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2">
                          <Button Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                            <Button.Template>
                              <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="/Aisys.XStorage.Dashboard;component/Images/Refresh.png"/>
                              </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                          </Button>
                          <Button Width="20" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveDiagramCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type bl:DragDockPanelHost}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <Button.Template>
                              <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="/Aisys.XStorage.Dashboard;component/Images/Remove.png"/>
                              </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                          </Button>
                          <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowPropertiesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type bl:DragDockPanelHost}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                            <Button.Template>
                              <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="/Aisys.XStorage.Dashboard;component/Images/Preferences.png"/>
                              </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                          </Button>
                          <ToggleButton x:Name="MaximizeToggleButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsMaximized}" Margin="0,5,5,0" Width="25" Height="25" Cursor="Hand">
                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                              <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Image Source="/Aisys.XStorage.Dashboard;component/Images/Maximize.png" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                              </ControlTemplate>
                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                          </ToggleButton>
                        </WrapPanel>
                      </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Separator VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource elementTempSelector}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </bl:DragDockPanelHost.DefaultPanelStyle>
    </bl:DragDockPanelHost>
```

XAML of chart:

```
  <Grid>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}" LegendLocation="Right" Name="chart">
      <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:Axis Title="Zeit" LabelFormatter="{Binding XFormatter}">
        </lvc:Axis>
      </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
  </Grid>
```

If I'm choosing LineSeries, everything works fine. But when I'm using ColumnSeries nothing is shown. You can see, that the axis is redrawn and the separators move. The legend is also drawn, but there are no columns visible.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere but for some reason **if you have too many data points for the size of the graph, then none of the columns will display**. You can either try reducing the number of data points until it works (in my case 90 data points wouldn't display, but 30 would), or [on ColumnSeries there is a property ColumnPadding](https://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/wpf/LiveCharts-Wpf-ColumnSeries) that you can turn down to zero and see if that helps.